# Android emulator window stays on top after Alt+Tab

Tags: ubuntu, android-emulator, ubuntu-unity

I'm running Ubuntu 16.04 with the default window manager.  When using Android Emulator, I sometimes switch to it using Alt+Tab and then out of it in the same way.  When I switch out, its window stays on top, even if the window I switch to becomes active.

When clicking on another window to switch, the Emulator window becomes hidden as expected.

When using Alt+Tab again to switch from window A to another window B, the Emulator window becomes hidden as well.

"Always on Top" window flag is not set on the Emulator window.

Anyone knows what I can do to force the Emulator window to become hidden the first time around when I switch out of it via Alt+Tab?

Answer (score 7):

Android emulator consists of two windows, so both windows must be "always on top".

Fast way in terminal (toogle always_on_top):

```
wmctrl -i -r $(wmctrl -l | grep ' Android Emulator - ' | sed -e 's/\s.*$//g') -b toggle,above
wmctrl -i -r $(wmctrl -l | grep ' Emulator$' | sed -e 's/\s.*$//g') -b toggle,above
```

or

1. Check "Always on top" for "Android emulator" window:

[image]

2. Select the second window on your dash panel called as "emulator":

[image]

3. After that enter shortcut <kbd>alt + space</kbd> and check "Always on top":

[image]

Taken from here https://stackoverflow.com/a/38274325/1772410